# How to get URL path to a Module in yii with rewrite engine on ?

Tags: .htaccess, yii, yii-extensions, yii-components

Hello and thanks for reading .

I have installed the yii user module and iam trying to link to the profile page using the following code ;

```
 'url' => Yii::app()->getModule('user')->profileUrl),
```

in my main.php i have the following;

```
'urlManager' => array(
        'urlFormat' => 'path',
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'caseSensitive' => false,
        'rules' => array(
            'gii' => 'gii',
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<action>' => 'site/<action>',
        ),
    ),
```

and in my htaccess file i have this ;

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

It works and i get redirected to `http://localhost/spob/user/profile` but when i clcik on another link that links to my protected/views eg `'url' => array('employercontract/index')),` i get the following error `Error 404
Unable to resolve the request "user/employercontract/index".` The correct path would be `http://localhost/spob/employercontract/index` without the user path.

I think that the problem could be in the main.php , where i declare the rules, any suggestion would be much appreciated i have been trying for the whole morning to solve this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correct...

Try to replace this

```
'url' => array('employercontract/index'))
```

with this

```
'url' => array('/employercontract/index'))
```

Note leading slash. This will tell UrlManager that link should be created based on site root. Whithout it - link is based on current module(user module in your case).

I hope this helps.

Comment: it did help , it's the correct answer thanks for the explanation also